# Parse all xml files in a directory

Tags: javascript, ajax, electron

I'm looking for a way to parse a bunch of xml files in the following directory structure:

```
db/
  -> dir1/
       -> file.xml
  -> dir2/
       -> file.xml
  ...
```

All xml files have the same name but under different directories.

Prior to this I had a single xml file that I was parsing using ajax like so:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "db/file.xml",
          dataType: "xml",
          success: function (xml) {
              // parsing done here
          }
      });
  });
```

Is there a similar way to do the above but recursively? Thanks in advance!

Comment: well are the directories known? JavaScript can not just find directories from the browser.

Comment: dir1, dir2, ... and so on are not known, but they are all local, I was hoping I can pass in * to iterate through all of them. I'm using Electron if it helps

Comment: If you need access to local filesystem, tou need to use ds.readDir. https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-get-files-from-a-directory/18871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have been too early to post, but I ended up using xml2js:

```
const path = require('path')
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

$(document).ready(function() {
    var files = glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, '../db/*/*.xml'));
    var counter = 0;
    files.forEach(function(f) {
        fs.readFile(f, function(err, data) {
            var parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray : false});
            parser.parseString(data, function(err, xml) {
                // parsing done here
            });
            counter++;
            if (counter === files.length) {
                $(document).trigger('completed-xml-db-parse');
            }
        });
    });
});
```